# Play video on QT using OMXPLAYER

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

I want to play videos using Qt on a Raspberry-Pi. Can someone please give me a source code and a little description of how to. I would like to use omxPlayer

I really wanna do this kind of thing [sample project on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=6jSQh84apgw)

Answer (score 1):

this should be a good start, even if I have not tested it, seems well documented (blog post, etc):

https://github.com/carlonluca/pi